# SELECT query executes for a very long time occasionally

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a really wierd problem in my MySQL InnoDB database. I have following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.idProject AS idProject, p.name AS name, 0 AS isConfirm
FROM Projects p
    JOIN team_project tp ON (p.idProject = tp.idProject) 
    JOIN projtimes pt ON (p.idProject = pt.idProject) 
    JOIN CalledTimesTbl ctt ON (p.idProject = ctt.idProject)
    LEFT JOIN NextCalls nc ON (ctt.idCustomer = nc.idCustomer 
        AND ctt.idProject = nc.idProject) 
WHERE tp.idTeam = 158
    AND p.activated = 1 
    AND current_date >= p.projStart
    AND current_date < p.confirmStart 
    AND pt.invitesCount < pt.maxPerPresentation
    AND (nc.idCustomer IS NULL OR nc.nextCall < now())
ORDER BY p.name
```

Generally the query runs fine, but sometimes - for example when I set `tp.idTeam = 147` it runs really slow (like 10 or 20 seconds). When I create alternative team and adjust proper tables values to have the same result with different `idTeam` value - the query executes in a fraction of second.

I profiled the query and noticed that when query executes slowly - there is one thing that consumes most of the time:

```
Copying to tmp table      | 12.489197
```

I was a bit surprised that the query creates a tmp table but ok - it creates it every time the query executes - also when it executes fast.
I just add that db is designed well, there are all needed foreign keys, etc.

How to find the source of the slow executions and eliminate it?

EDIT: `EXPLAIN` results:

```
id   select_type   table   type     possible_keys                    key              key_len   ref                                                   rows   Extra                             
1    SIMPLE        tp      ref      unique_row,idTeam                idTeam           4         const                                                 56     Using temporary; Using filesort   
1    SIMPLE        p       eq_ref   PRIMARY,projStart,confirmStart   PRIMARY          4         xxx.tp.idProject                                      1      Using where                       
1    SIMPLE        pt      ref      uniq_projtimes                   uniq_projtimes   4         xxx.tp.idProject                                      1      Using where; Distinct             
1    SIMPLE        ctt     ref      idProject                        idProject        4         xxx.tp.idProject                                      3966   Using index; Distinct             
1    SIMPLE        nc      eq_ref   PRIMARY,idProject                PRIMARY          8         xxx.ctt.idCustomer,xxx.tp.idProject                   1      Using where; Distinct
```

EDIT2: Results of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` first for fast query, second for the slow one.

```
id   select_type   table   type     possible_keys                    key              key_len   ref                                           rows    filtered   Extra                  1    SIMPLE        tp      ref      unique_row,idTeam                idTeam           4         const                                                 1       100        Using temporary         
1    SIMPLE        p       eq_ref   PRIMARY,projStart,confirmStart   PRIMARY          4         xxx.tp.idProject                              1       100        Using where             
1    SIMPLE        pt      ref      uniq_projtimes                   uniq_projtimes   4         xxx.tp.idProject                              1       100        Using where; Distinct   
1    SIMPLE        ctt     ref      idProject                        idProject        4         xxx.tp.idProject                              46199   100        Using index; Distinct   
1    SIMPLE        nc      eq_ref   PRIMARY,idProject                PRIMARY          8         xxx.ctt.idCustomer,xxx.tp.idProject           1       100        Using index; Distinct  

id   select_type   table   type     possible_keys                    key              key_len   ref                                           rows   filtered   Extra                                
1    SIMPLE        p       eq_ref   PRIMARY,projStart,confirmStart   PRIMARY          4         xxx.ctt.idProject                             1      100        Using where                          
1    SIMPLE        pt      ref      uniq_projtimes                   uniq_projtimes   4         xxx.ctt.idProject                             1      100        Using where; Distinct                
1    SIMPLE        tp      ref      unique_row,idTeam                unique_row       8         xxx.pt.idProject,const                        1      100        Using where; Using index; Distinct   
1    SIMPLE        nc      eq_ref   PRIMARY,idProject                PRIMARY          8         xxx.ctt.idCustomer,xxx.tp.idProject           1      100        Using index; Distinct
```

Comment: Creating a tmp table is necessary for this query; you ask for a sorted resultset from a join; that often requires MySQL to create a so-called tmp table, then sort it.  Run `EXPLAIN` on your query, with the offending idTeam, and show us the results.

Comment: Added `EXPLAIN` result. I noticed that removing `LEFT JOIN NextCalls` makes it go really fast, but I need that condition too.

Comment: Is the EXPLAIN with idTeam = 158, not with 147? Please provide an EXPLAIN where the query runs slow. Cause this explain looks actually quite good.

Comment: Question: In MySQL, are joins optimized when the where condition is made part of the inner join-condition? For example here, `JOIN team_project tp ON (p.idProject = tp.idProject and tp.idTeam = 158 and p.activated=1)`

Comment: @Tim This is not a question of `JOIN or WHERE`, it's all about indexes.

Comment: @Joe You may have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html See what the differences are when you execute the query with different idTeams.

Comment: @tombom - this is explain for the slow idTeam.

Comment: @tombom: not sure what you mean by "about indexes" -- some index nodes on idTeam have many many values versus others that have only a few?

Comment: @Tim It means, it doesn't matter if you put a column in the join or in the where condition.

Comment: @Joe In the slow query you are not joining to table CalledTimesTbl. Why?

Comment: @tombom I noticed that there is no ctt but it is the same query (except idTeam) and result is the same.
Now it started to work properly. Unfortunately same situation occured yesterday. I guess I'll wait for tomorrow, probably same problem will happen and I'll try to debug it again.

Comment: Are those explain plan good? The 2nd one doesn't show any link to ctt.

Comment: @Younes - I cannot recreate it, because after few days - the problem is gone. I don't like situation when problems came in and then came out all by themselves. It always gives me impression that there is still sth wrong. Unfortunately I can't reproduce it now. If the problem will occur again - I'll do some updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this adjusted query. (It will join less rows)

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.idProject AS idProject, p.name AS name, 0 AS isConfirm
FROM Projects p
    JOIN projtimes pt ON 
        p.idProject = pt.idProject
        AND p.activated = 1
        AND current_date >= p.projStart
        AND current_date < p.confirmStart
        AND pt.invitesCount < pt.maxPerPresentation
    JOIN team_project tp ON 
        p.idProject = tp.idProject
        AND tp.idTeam = 158
    JOIN CalledTimesTbl ctt ON (p.idProject = ctt.idProject)
    LEFT JOIN NextCalls nc ON (ctt.idCustomer = nc.idCustomer 
        AND ctt.idProject = nc.idProject) 
WHERE (nc.idCustomer IS NULL OR nc.nextCall < now())
ORDER BY p.name
```

Comment: Thx. Still - I was wondering some time ago whether moving the conditions from `where` to `join` clause results in better performance. My simple tests results show pretty much no difference. Are there any tests or mechanisms description showing that conditions in `join` are better than `where`?

Comment: hmm... I always thought there was but after doing research online it looks like the mysql optimizer may do that for you anyway...